# Unexpected NaN value when importing CSV into numpy array using genfromtxt()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

Does anyone know why the first element in my numpy array is always nan when importing the following csv data using genfromtxt?

92,99,86,81 58,7,16,47 57,52,4,66 71,60,72,8 79,63,90,7 40,60,88,68 41,9,93,58 52,21,28,53 1,9,72,88 61,26,33,51

I have attached a screenshot to this post to show the exact issue. In this, the line of code

x = np.genfromtxt('../data/example_data.csv', delimiter=',')

imports a 10 by 4 array into the variable x, where the elements in the array are the values in my csv file, except for the element in position (0,0), which is nan.

[image: Issue]

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Cheers.

Comment: The default `dtype` is `float`; if it can't make a float number from a column value (such as a label) it puts a `nan` there.  If you were using `loadtxt` you'd get an error.

Comment: If you've shared the data exactly as it appears in your file, then the problem is the spaces between some of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a typical csv file, when you read the values the top-left value is empty as you can see. So that might be the reason.